# AntTweakBar callbacks throwing " ';' expected" error before method

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl, visual-studio-2012, glfw

After following a tutorial to create a basic particle system, I began implementing AntTweakBar to get a basic UI going. This was going well, everything draws OK. But once I started adding the callback functions it started to go a little haywire, claiming that it's throwing this in the middle of a method definition:

> Intellisense: expected a ';'

The method in question is:

```
void GLFWCALL OnMouseRight(int glfwButton, int glfwAction)
{
    if( !TwEventMouseButtonGLFW(glfwButton, glfwAction) )   // Send event to AntTweakBar
    {
        if(glfwButton == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT)
            computeMatricesFromInputs();
        else
        // Event has not been handled by AntTweakBar
        // Do something if needed.
    }
}
```

The error is apparently popping up between the name `OnMouseRight` and the following parentheses. How do I get rid of this error? I'm coding in OpenGL (using GLFW and GLEW) with C++ and I have been following the steps on this [page on the AntTweakBar site](http://anttweakbar.sourceforge.net/doc/tools:anttweakbar:howto). I have looked up most of the GLFW documentation already and not found much. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, after a long night's work at this problem and trawling through GLFW's documentation again I noticed that the problem lay with the macro `GLFWCALL`. C++ was treating it as a method in it's own right and as a result ignoring the actual method. GLFW's documentation explained why:

> The `GLFWCALL` macro, which made callback functions use `__stdcall`  on Windows, has been removed. GLFW is written in C, not Pascal. Removing this macro means there's one less thing for users of GLFW to remember, i.e. the requirement to mark all callback functions with `GLFWCALL`. It also simplifies the creation of `DLLs` and `DLL` link libraries, as there's no need to explicitly disable `@n` entry point suffixes.

On removing `GLFWCALL` and following the advice of @vitaut my program now handles the right mouse inputs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing statement after `else` which is causing the error:

```
    if(glfwButton == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT)
        computeMatricesFromInputs();
    else
      // ^ no statement here
```

You can add a semicolon as Intellisense suggests or an empty compound statement `{}`:

```
    if(glfwButton == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT) {
        computeMatricesFromInputs();
    } else {
      // Event has not been handled by AntTweakBar
      // Do something if needed.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks vitaut, though I'm not sure the problem is the else statement. This was the format followed by an example piece and there were no errors thrown there, despite the lack of code in the else statement. Also the error persists on removing the else statement entirely which is doubly confusing. Any thoughts?